# Can a router block localhost (127.0.0.1) traffic on a server?

Tags: firewall, router, localhost

Our web server was just switched to a V-LAN with some very strict firewall rules. Basically they closed every inbound and outbound port unless we specifically needed it.

We have some services running locally on the server that handle requests on specific ports (58585 and 45454), but the requests are made by the web application itself to 127.0.0.1.

This stopped working once they switched our web server to the new V-LAN. Is it possible the router can actually BLOCK localhost traffic? Windows Firewall is disabled so it cannot possibly be the culprit.

**UPDATE**

Turns out the service was not up and running.

However, the lesson to be learned is that 127.0.0.1 can NOT be affected by a router firewall because the packets are completely restricted to the local computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that traffic should never leave the host. Can you ping 127.0.0.1? Have you taken a network trace to verify that something unexpected isn't happening?

Comment: Ping comes back okay. Tracert comes back single line with to the computer name. pinging localhost gives me ::1: even though IPv6 is disabled.

Comment: Another wierd thing. This is a web server hosting on port 80. Yet going to http://localhost gives me a "Web Page Not Found" error.

Comment: Nevermind. Problem was the service was not running on that port due to the IP address change. Sorry for the perlextion!